# Change list of items on JCombo box

Tags: java, swing

I am having a list of items in a JCombo box, based on an another event I want to change the items in the list .
 I have a method like this

```
void changeChoices(Array[] foo) 
 {
   JComboBox.removeAllItems();

  for (int i=0;i < foo.length ; ++i)
     JComboBox.addItem(foo[i]);

 }
```

is this Valid??

Comment: Does it work when you've tried it?

Comment: @vasu1486 check the answers please.

Comment: @vasu1486 can you tick accept on my answer? if it has done your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is **not valid** in terms of syntax.

- `foo` seems to be array of `Array` objects, are you sure you are using
  a combobox of array of `Array` objects?
- You have `JComboBox.removeAllItems();`, this is not valid since
  `JComboBox` class doesn't have a static method called `removeAllItems()`.
- Inside for loop you use `JComboBox.addItem(foo[i]);`,this is not
  valid again due to a similar reason explained above, `JComboBox` class doesn't have a static method called `addItem()`.

A valid method could be like this one:

```
String[] oldValues = new String [5];
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(oldValues);

public void changeChoices ( String [] newValues )
{
   comboBox.removeAllItems();

   for( int i = 0; i < newValues.length; i++ )
       comboBox.addItem( newValues [ i ] );
}
```

Last but not least, if you are removing all values from a combobox and adding completely new ones, then you should handle their corresponding events in your code. You are possibly adding an `ItemListener` to your combobox and implementing selected item events in `itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)` method. So you should implement what would happen if a newly added value is selected from your combobox. I hope this post is useful and makes sense.

Comment: this is job for JComboBox's Model, but good answer for newbee +1